# South African Unrest clarification

Tags: twilight-struggle

The mid war card **South African Unrest** seemed perfectly clear to me, until I read the Twilight Strategy article on it. How, exactly, can the event be played?

---

**South African Unrest** reads:

> USSR either adds 2 Influence in South Africa or adds 1 influence in South Africa and 2 Influence in any countries adjacent to South Africa.

The confusion comes in from the [Twilight Strategy article](http://twilightstrategy.com/2012/10/16/south-african-unrest/):

> Despite a possible interpretation of the event’s text otherwise, you cannot use this for 1 in Angola and 1 in Botswana: it has to be 1 in South Africa plus 2 in Angola or 2 in Botswana.

---

Prior to reading Twilight Strategy I thought the following 4 options could be played:

1. Place 2 Influence in South Africa.
2. Place 1 Influence in South Africa, and 2 Influence in Angola.
3. Place 1 Influence in South Africa, and 2 Influence in Botswana.
4. Place 1 Influence in South Africa, 1 Influence in Angola, and 1 Influence in Botswana.

I think the Twilight Strategy note is saying that #4 is out. Is that right? If that was so, shouldn't the card read "In any *one country* adjacent to South Africa"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text on this card was changed from the second edition to the Deluxe Edition, altering *any country* to *any countries*.

[From the Official FAQs:](http://www.gmtgames.com/nnts/FAQv5.pdf)

> **#53 South African Unrest**
>
> Note the Deluxe Edition card text allows the option of 2 Influence in "...any countries 
>   adjacent to South Africa." effectively allowing one each in Angola and Botswana.

This allows the 2 influence to be placed either in Angola or Botswana or split between both countries, getting one each.

Comment: So, is Twilight Strategy wrong (or out of date)? Are all 4 options possible?

Comment: Yes all 4 options are possible in the current (deluxe) edition. The second edition wording of the card didn't allow for splitting the 2 influence so the alteration suggests a rule change.